# Issue with python multi threading and socket connections

Tags: python, sockets, networking, tcp, python-multithreading

I recently picked up python and I am trying to learn more about networking. I came across a problem, where I am trying to both listen and send data at the same time using multi threading. Here is the code:

```
import socket
from threading import Thread


name = ""


s = socket.socket()

def Main():
    print("What is your name?")
    name = input("Name: ")
    Connect()

def Connect():
    host = '127.0.0.1'
    port = 5000


    s.connect((host, port))
    Thread(target=Send()).start()
    print("oh")
    Listen()


def Listen():
    while True:
        data, addr = s.recvfrom(1024)
        data = data.decode('utf-8')
        if not data:
            break
        print(data)

def Send():
    message = input(name + ": ")
    while message != 'q':
        s.send(message.encode("utf-8"))
        message = input(name + ": ")
    s.close()
Main()
```

The problem is that when the `Thread` is created, the program is stuck in the while loop of the `Send()` function, and it never calls the `Listen()` function.
I added a `print()` function to debug whether anything happens after the thread is created.

This is the output that I got:

> What is your name?
>
> Name: FlowR
>
> : test
>
> :

Comment: Can you show the output of running the program?

Comment: I added the input, and included a debug `print()` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling the `Send()` function instead of passing it as parameters, that's why it blocks.

Drop the `()` after `target=Send()`:

```
Thread(target=Send).start()
```

Comment: Thank you so much!